# VBA Userforms - How to keep checkbox selections updated?

Tags: excel, vba

So the title may not make a lot of sense, so I'll try to explain as best as I can.
As you can see in the image below, I have multiple checkboxes on the left (let's just focus on those now).

Everytime I tick certain checkboxes and click on "Next step" the captions of those checkboxes are added to a combobox.

Let's imagine that I select the first 2 and click on "Next Step". While I'm on the next step I realize I don't want one of the selected checkboxes and I want to remove it. If I go back and deselect it, it doesn't remove if from the combobox and it's not like I can just delete it from there.

[image]

The code I'm using to send the selected checkbox captions to the combobox is as follows:

```
If speGro = True And speGroT = True Then
    SEG_MODULE.seg_cbb_selDim.AddItem "Caption Name"
End If
```

Basically I repeat this if statement for all checkboxes.

Is there a way to make sure ONLY the selected checkboxes appear on the combobox?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is `speGro` the name of the checkbox then? You are already checking if it's true or not, so the question is not very clear. What exactly is the problem? Are you trying to loop through them or something?

Comment: Everything works. When I select a checkbox it gets sent to the combobox. I just wanted to know if, for example, I go back and deselect a checkbox it automatically gets removed from the combobox (which is not happening).

Comment: Oh. That's going to be much more complicated. You would have to loop thru the items in the combo box looking for the items you want to remove, assuming you also know which items need to be removed.

Comment: Oh I see, it's probably not worth it then. I just wanted to create the best user experience possible. Thank you anyway!!

Comment: When you uncheck it, would you be pressing "Next Step" or do you want that to happen automatically?

Comment: I would be pressing "Next Step" again. :)

Comment: Since you are pressing `Next Step`, then it is really simply actually ;) Clear the combobox. The checked items will automatically get added again. No need to remove specific items. Something like `ComboBox1.Clear` and then `If CheckBox1.Value = True Then ComboBox1.AddItem CheckBox1.Caption`

Comment: Oh, that sounds good! Where should I insert the ```Combobox1.clear```? You can see my code above, for reference. :)

Comment: I did it already, thank you it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) Since I had already started posting the answer, I went ahead and posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you uncheck it, would you be pressing "Next Step" or do you want that to happen automatically? – Siddharth Rout 41 mins ago

> I would be pressing "Next Step" again. :) – soraia635 23 mins ago

Since you are pressing `Next Step`, then it is really simple actually ;) Clear the combobox. The checked items will automatically get added again. No need to remove specific items. Lets say your userform has `Checkbox1-Checkbox2`, `ComboBox1-ComboBox2` and `CommandButton1` then you can do something like this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ComboBox1.Clear
    ComboBox2.Clear
    
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then ComboBox1.AddItem CheckBox1.Caption
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then ComboBox1.AddItem CheckBox2.Caption
    
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then ComboBox2.AddItem CheckBox1.Caption
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then ComboBox2.AddItem CheckBox2.Caption
End Sub
```